# CSS Animation Bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

i have created a signup / login form. To this I have created an animation to switch between the two. However there is a bug in my animation, and I cannot find the cause for it.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="message signup-message">
      <h1>Welcome to website!</h1>
      <h4>Get started immediately by creating an account below!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="message login-message">
      <h1>Welcome back!</h1>
      <h4>Log in below!</h4>
    </div>
    <form class="form signup-form" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="first-signup" required autocomplete="off">
        <label>
          First name<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="last-signup" required autocomplete="off">
        <label>
          Last name<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="uid-signup" required autocomplete="off">
        <label>
          Username<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="email-signup" required autocomplete="off">
        <label>
          E-mail<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="pwd-signup" required autocomplete="off">
        <label>
          Password<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="pwd-repeat-signup" required autocomplete="off">
        <label>
          Repeat password<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="spec form-group">
        <span>Already have an account? </span><a href="#" onclick="toggle_login_signup()">Login</a>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" name="submit-signup">sign up <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <form class="form login-form" action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="uid-login" required autocomplete="off">
        <label>
          Username/E-mail<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="pwd-login" required autocomplete="off">
        <label>
          Password<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="spec form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me"> Remember me<br>
        <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a><br>
        <span>No account? </span><a href="#" onclick="toggle_login_signup()">Sign up</a>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" name="submit-signup">Login <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes hide {
  from{
    left:50%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to{
    left: 20%;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@keyframes show {
  from{
    left:90%;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  to{
    left:50%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
let toggle_login = false;
let toggle_login_signup = function(){

  let login_form = document.querySelector(".login-form");
  let signup_form = document.querySelector(".signup-form");
  let login_msg = document.querySelector(".login-message");
  let signup_msg = document.querySelector(".signup-message");

  if (toggle_login === false) {
    signup_form.style.animation = "hide .5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) forwards";
    signup_msg.style.animation = "hide .5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) forwards";
    login_form.style.animation = "show .5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) forwards .3s";
    login_msg.style.animation = "show .5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) forwards .3s";

    toggle_login = true;
  }
  else {
    login_form.style.animation = "hide .5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) forwards";
    signup_form.style.animation = "show .5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) forwards .3s";
    login_msg.style.animation = "hide .5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) forwards";
    signup_msg.style.animation = "show .5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) forwards .3s";

    toggle_login = false;
  }

}
```

https://codepen.io/becckman/pen/XorEdJ

as you can see, the signup form appears for a second before the animation occurs. Can you find the cause for this? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What kind of bug do you have?.

Comment: At first the signup form is showing. When I press the already have an account login button, the login form slides in from the right with the animation. However when I press the " no account, signup" button, the signup form first appears in the middle for a sec, and after that the animation occurs.And I cant find the cause for this

If you look at the codepen, you will better understand what I mean. Hard to explain in words :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right it's done. It was a matter of how do you call the classes in js.

See below.

```
    let toggle_login = false;
let toggle_login_signup = function(){

  let login_form = document.querySelector(".login-form");
  let signup_form = document.querySelector(".signup-form");
  let login_msg = document.querySelector(".login-message");
  let signup_msg = document.querySelector(".signup-message");

    if (!toggle_login) {

    signup_form.style.animation = "hide .5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) forwards";
    signup_msg.style.animation = "hide .5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) forwards";

            login_form.style.animation = "show .5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) forwards .3s";
    login_msg.style.animation = "show .5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) forwards .3s";



    toggle_login = true;
  }
  else {
    login_form.style.animation = "hide .5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) forwards";
    login_msg.style.animation = "hide .5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) forwards";
              signup_form.style.animation = "show .5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) both .5s";
             signup_msg.style.animation = "show .5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) both .5s";   



    toggle_login = false;
  }

}
```

The buggy behaviour was, because the animation-fill-mode value.

Use `both`, so it can apply the first & last keyframe value to the element.

Now there is no such buggy behavior. Glad to help ;)

Comment: Have you tested it and it works? Because for me now it doesnt show up at all. Its just gone. And the headers overlap.

Comment: sorry the issue still in there. Let me see it again.

Comment: fount anything? :/

Comment: I would suggest putting the animation settings inside CSS classes and use JS only to switch the classnames on the two form elements. This way it's easier to maintain, both codes are cleaner and there's less hassle with cross browser issues in animation syntax for older browsers (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

Comment: @Yoarthur Thanks for the help!

Comment: @beckman There are a lot of tutorials and sites, but a good starting point could be https://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: @Philip Thanks for the tip! Will try that.